# Connect to remote server in android

Tags: android, web-services, remote-server

i have developed an android applcation. (with volley) i have a webservice and currently its on my localhost. (using xampp)

My url strings in my AppConfig class as following:

```
public class AppConfig {
// Server user login url
public static String URL_LOGIN = "http://10.0.2.2/webservice/login.php";

// Server guide details url
private static String URL_GET_GUIDE_PROFILE = "http://10.0.2.2/webservice/getGuideProfile.php";

}
```

now i have moved my php files to a remote server using filezilla. its a managed wordpress hosting. my domain is something like this,

www.exampletouristguides.com

i cant figure out the urls of my files now. i have tried,

```
http://www.exampletouristguides.com/login.php
ftp://ftpusername@exampletouristguides.com/login.php
http://www.exampletouristguides.com/ftpusername/login.php
```

but nothing works. i get this error message

```
E/Volley: [219] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for
```

filezilla shows the path of my files like this,

```
/home/ftpusername/login.php
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try the first url without "www."

Answer (score 0):

Use postman Google Chrome plugin to check End points(APIS). Then you will come to know what exactly root cause.

[Postman tutorial](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/blog_mentions)

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. i had to move my files inside the /home/html folder in my remote server.